# localhost:8080 stopping my reply from API

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

I am doing a tutorial on React with Reflux.
But Im getting a 404 on the query response. I think it has todo with the `url` sent to fetch the data.

When I do a console.log on the variable 'url' I get the following:
`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=4e26b7e43fe918dbc620bbf34456a9de&q=New York,us`
but in the Network Request tab I see the following in the Request

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=4e26b7e43fe918dbc620bbf34456a9de&q=New%20York,us
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
```

If I copy this address and paste it into the address bar, sure thing I dont get a respons, but if a delete the `localhost:8080` from the address, I get a perfect response from the API.

Why is the `localhost:8080` being added, and if it is wrong how do I fix it?

Here is my Action that I created to go and fetch the data.

**ACTION:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
const API_KEY = '4e26b7e43fe918dbc620bbf34456a9de';
const ROOT_URL = `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city) {
    var url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;

    const request = axios.get(url);

    return {
        type: FETCH_WEATHER,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

**This worked, but can anyone explain why maybe?**
on the url variable, I manually added `http://` and this then caused the url request not to prepend `http://localhost:8080`

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = '4e26b7e43fe918dbc620bbf34456a9de';
const ROOT_URL = `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city) {

    var url = `http://${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;

    const request = axios.get(url);

    return {
        type: FETCH_WEATHER,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

Comment: This behaviour is related to the library that you're using to make the request (axios). Take a look at the help info on 'axios'. Especially the info about 'baseURL'. https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config